# Back Icon over the image

Tags: css

I am trying to add an icon just over the image(top left corner) but I have confusion in doing this.
I am planning to give white color to the icon. but if the image background is white that time it is not visible. what should be the best approach to do this.

Something Like this
[imge with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmiif.png)

Comment: Add some black overlay to the parent container (the element with the image background) so the white icon is more visible and add `position: relative` to it, and to it's `button` child `position: absolute` with your `top/left` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the icon some kind of outline or a border to make sure it will be visible on a background with the same color.

Comment: Yes, I Tried this approach but it doesn't look good.Can we have some other option to do this?

Comment: Well it just comes back to your liking, whether or not something looks good to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a div inside another div. The first one is the backgroud image and the second is the icon. With "position" you can move the icon div on the top left corner. Then you can give the color you like to the icon.